# Computational Complexity of Ramsey Numbers

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, co.combinatorics

1. What is the computational complexity of computing [Ramsey numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem) $(n,m) \mapsto R(n,m)$? Is it inside PH?
2. Would it be easier to compute $R$ if PH=P?

Comment: Have you seen this question:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/204254/what-is-the-complexity-of-determining-ramsey-number ?  It sounds as though the complexity of Ramsey number computation is still open; however, if it does lie in PH as you suggest and PH collapses to P, then no, it would not be difficult to compute them.  Also, see:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Ramsey_numbers .  It seems that the worst-case complexity is O(c^(n(2))).

Comment: Thanks. I had not seen the Q. As you pointed out it seems to be still open. I was assuming it lies in the PH, but am/was not sure where and how to prove it. Thus, Q2. (i.e. Assuming P=NP, then what can we say about the complexity for finding them in that scenario). But, I think the question of finding them assuming the collapse seems to be open. The worst case complexity for a particular Graph size is  O(c^(n(2))), but we have no idea how fast the graph grows with the Ramsey parameters, as asymptotic bound gap grows exponentially.

Comment: The question does not make sense to me. Polynomial hierarchy consists of decision problems, whereas you are asking about a function problem, so you are comparing apples and oranges. Moreover, the Ramsey numbers are exponentially large, hence you need exponential time just to write them down, let alone to compute them, and having oracles from PH cannot help that.

Comment: I am naive regarding Ramsey Numbers with that disclaimer: The asymptotic bounds are exponential in nature, but I am confused as this quote from you on the other problem: 'We don’t really know much about the Ramsey numbers. It’s perfectly possible they are given by a nice formula, computable in polynomial time.' Thus, assuming we may have such a formula, we might somehow (no idea how) be able to reduce the verification of those numbers to a polynomial time problem. Hence, as far as I understand, their calculation (and even verification) might be strictly Polynomial.

Comment: You are quoting me out of context, which concerned problems whose inputs were actual graphs, hence the size was effectively given in unary. I even explicitly pointed that out in the same comment thread. No matter what formulas might exist, (1) calculation of Ramsey numbers is a function problem, hence it is a priori meaningless to ask about its containment in a class of decision problems, and (2) the output size is exponential in the input size, hence it cannot be computed in subexponential time. If you don't understand such basic facts, you can't understand the question you're asking.

Comment: FWIW, Ramsey numbers are computable in $\mathrm{FEXP^{NP}}$ using straightforward binary search.

Comment: There are many cases in which there is a polytime Turing reduction from a function problem to a decision problem.  Of course, given that the output size is exponentially larger than the input, there can't be a reduction to a problem in P...although maybe there is one to a problem in PH, assuming PH doesn't collapse?  Of course, I'm not saying I'm optimistic; demonstrating such a fact would necessarily prove that P != NP.

Comment: @PhilipWhite: No, no, no, no. A polynomial-time oracle Turing machine cannot write more than polynomially many bits of output. It makes no difference whatsoever if the oracle is from P, from PH, or highly undecidable.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek:  Ok, my mistake...but my broader point is still correct:  It is not wrong to compare function problems to decision problems.  E.g., if the OP had asked whether the function problem of solving SAT is in P, that would make sense.  Also, there is such a thing as FPH, even if Ramsey numbers can't be found in it.  Finally, there is surely some EXPTIME decision-problem analog for Ramsey numbers...and there is no proof that EXP != PH, at least not yet.

Comment: @PhilipWhite: No. It makes sense to ask if a function problem *reduces* to a class of decision problems by a particular kind of reductions. It doesn't make sense to ask if the function problem *is* in such a class. If the OP asked whether a function problem is in P, the answer would be an unequivocal no. P is not FP, and PH is not FPH.

Comment: Much thanks for the informative comments. As I said, I did not have much background in Ramsey Theory. The trigger was a rather humorous note regarding the PH Collapse (http://www.scottaaronson.com/writings/phcollapse.pdf) . And was wondering what other concrete problems (not just Complexity Classes), that wold survive the complete PH Collapse, would be open, and would be worthwhile attempting to get a concrete solution - Algorithm, Formula (functional, decision etc). In this regard I stumbled upon Ramsey Numbers. Hence, the Q.

Comment: What I mean is that it would make sense to compare them...not that it would be precisely correct to ask if solving SAT for the satisfying literal assignment is P.  Of course P is not FP and PH is not FPH.